# APC script locks ups

Tags: php, apc, file-in-use

***UPDATE - This is not a problem with APC but actually my server when I edit a script, save, and re-run it. The page loads continuously and the file locks due to my httpd.exe process whether APC is involved or not. I suggest a moderator close this question.***

<strike>So I just installed PHP's APC and verified that it's installed and working with phpinfo() but I'm running into a few problems actually using it. I'm using the below code on a page to experiment with APC, and when I load the page it comes up as expected with It Worked on it.</strike>

However, when I refresh the page *after changing the script* it just tries to load the page continuously. Not only that, but the code (apc/index.php) becomes locked off from any kind of editing due to it being used by another program. Even when shutting down my entire server and closing the page it's still in use by another program. The only way to unlock it is to actually restart the whole computer. This happens everytime I try to run this script, so can anyone tell me what's going on?

```
<?php
$testvar = "It worked";
apc_add("test",$testvar);
print_r(apc_fetch("test"));
?>
```

**UPDATE** - My phpinfo on APC is shown [here](http://puu.sh/33TN6/b6fa1bbda8.png), I'm running PHP 5.4.3 and Apache 2.2.22 on WAMP server 2.2, and the APC section in my php.ini is shown below.

```
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat = 1
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @mpratt I've added some additional information